# Why Laravel-livewire 'wire:model' not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 8.

My Livewire Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class SearchDropdown extends Component
{
    public $search = 'hello there';
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search-dropdown');
    }
}
```

Livewire blade

```
<div class="relative mt-3 md:mt-0">
    <input wire:model="search" type="text" class="bg-gray-800 text-sm rounded-full w-64 px-4 pl-8 py-1 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="absolute top-0">
        <svg class="fill-current w-4 text-gray-500 mt-2 ml-2" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M16.32 14.9l5.39 5.4a1 1 0 01-1.42 1.4l-5.38-5.38a8 8 0 111.41-1.41zM10 16a6 6 0 100-12 6 6 0 000 12z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="absolute text-sm bg-gray-800 rounded w-64 mt-4">
        <ul>
            <li class="border-b border-gray-700">
                <a href="#" class="block hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 py-3">{{ $search }}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="border-b border-gray-700">
                <a href="#" class="block hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 py-3">Avengers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="border-b border-gray-700">
                <a href="#" class="block hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 py-3">Avengers</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have included Livewire in my main.blade file

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Movie App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('/css/main.css') }}">
    <livewire:styles />
</head>
```

And this before the end of the body

```
<livewire:scripts />
```

Now when  I write something in my searchbox, it should have updated as i write, but it's not updating instead showing "hello there" - initial value of the $search variable.

P.S :
This is what its showing in my browser. For some reason livewire.js is getting error. How to fix this?
[image]

Comment: Try to clear the cache, `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: That didn't work. Thanks for the comment though. Didn't know I could clear the cache.

Comment: Nothing works, anyone?

Comment: Nothing works, anyone?

Answer (score 6):

you can just use

wire:model.live="search"

Answer (score 2):

Livewire only updates a component when an "action" is submitted—like pressing a submit button—not when a user types into a field. This cuts down on network requests and improves performance. To enable "live" updating as a user types, you can use `wire:model.live` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
@livewireStyles
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}">
```

and

```
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
        @livewireScripts
```

at your main layouts file, I think it should be worked

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, fixed it by adding

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js"></script>
```

in the main layout file because apparently, it was missing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your content with a `div` and `container` class in your Livewire blade.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="relative mt-3 md:mt-0">
    <input wire:model="search" type="text" class="bg-gray-800 text-sm rounded-full w-64 px-4 pl-8 py-1 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="absolute top-0">
        <svg class="fill-current w-4 text-gray-500 mt-2 ml-2" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path class="heroicon-ui" d="M16.32 14.9l5.39 5.4a1 1 0 01-1.42 1.4l-5.38-5.38a8 8 0 111.41-1.41zM10 16a6 6 0 100-12 6 6 0 000 12z"/></svg>
    </div>
    <div class="absolute text-sm bg-gray-800 rounded w-64 mt-4">
        <ul>
            <li class="border-b border-gray-700">
                <a href="#" class="block hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 py-3">{{ $search }}</a>
            </li>
            <li class="border-b border-gray-700">
                <a href="#" class="block hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 py-3">Avengers</a>
            </li>
            <li class="border-b border-gray-700">
                <a href="#" class="block hover:bg-gray-700 px-3 py-3">Avengers</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem and I solve it by just clearing cache ...

try to add this code snippet to your web route for fast clearance of caches

```
Route::get('/clear', function() {
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:cache');
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    return  "all cleared ...";

});
```

or just in cmd

```
Php artisan cache:clear
Php artisan route:cache

.... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that I had accidentally placed my livewire `<form>` inside another `<form>` tag. Oops!

Answer (score -1):

I followed the advise by @Kamlesh Paul and it worked.

you need to setup livewire base url

in config/livewire.php

```
'asset_url'  =>  env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

then in .env

```
APP_URL=your_app_url
```

Comment: I change to APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000 and works for me

Answer (score -1):

just run
php artisan optimize

that worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).