# Why am I getting 404 error on my livewire.js connection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 8. "wire:model" also not working because of this.
[image]

Comment: Here is my code details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65051509/why-laravel-livewire-wiremodel-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to setup livewire base url

in `config/livewire.php`

```php
'asset_url'  =>  env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),,
```

then in `.env`

```sh
APP_URL=your_app_url
```

Answer (score 0):

in config/livewire.php

'asset_url'  => url('/'),

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the livewire app url in `config/livewire.php`.

```
'app_url' =>  url('/'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the following code to your admin or control panel routes:

```
use Livewire\Controllers\HttpConnectionHandler;

Route::post('livewire/message/{name}', [HttpConnectionHandler::class, '__invoke']);
```

And remember to override the url using this one linear:

```js
<script>
    window.livewire_app_url = '{{route('admin.index')}}';
</script>
```

More detailed answer could be found here

[Laravel - Livewire, how to customize the global message URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69553897/laravel-livewire-how-to-customize-the-global-message-url)