# Laravel - Livewire, how to customize the global message URL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

Using a custom domain like the example below is not telling Livewire requests to be prefixed with the same subdomain `subdomain1` in this example:

```php
    Route::domain('subdomain1.'.env('APP_DOMAIN', 'localhost'))
             ->middleware(['web',.....])
             ->as('app.')
             ->group(base_path('routes/app.php'));
```

The problem is that the default callback for Livewire fetch endpoint which is `/livewire/message/{message}` is unfortunately using the root domain only and isn't based on where it has been called from. In my case from the `subdomain1` and as you can guess this means a different storage of the session bag. It's a different session in the first place.

So storing in session for the sub-domain is not the same as storing in the session itself. Nevertheless, there are other customizations which I need in order to encapsulate Livewire usage based on each sub-domain, image I have a multi-tenancy based project and I need such segregation.

Answer (score 4):

After some googling and based on a solution in [Livewire forums](https://forum.laravel-livewire.com/t/include-tenant-id-in-url-of-sendmessage/801/2):

I tailored it to be suitable **sub-domains usage**

- Step 1, added new route in `routes/app.php`:

```php
use Livewire\Controllers\HttpConnectionHandler;

// .....
// Notice that this root route has to be the same as the one in step2:
Route::get('/', [AppController::class, 'index'])->name('app.index');
// .....

Route::post('livewire/message/{name}', [HttpConnectionHandler::class, '__invoke']);
```

- Step2, In Blade just after `@livewireScripts`:

```html
@livewireScripts
<script>
    window.livewire_app_url = '{{route('app.index')}}';
</script>
```

And in case you are wondering about the config of Livewire, there is no need to change it. Just leave it as it is; `null`:

```php
'asset_url'  => null,
```